# How to access local variables within a class

Tags: python, oop

I am working on an assignment and am trying to access a local variable within a function that is in a class. Does anyone know how I can print a local variable from a function in a class? We are not allowed to print anything within our functions in the classes so I am wondering how I can do this.

```
def driver():
    q = my_queue.Queue_()
    for line in df:
        if 'received' in line:
            q.enqueue(line)
            print("Adding job " + q.new_item.job_ID + " to the queue with the timestamp: " + q.new_item.time_stamp + ".")
            print("The prority of the job is: " + q.new_item.job_priority)
            print("The job type is: " + q.new_item.job_type)
        if 'respond' in line:
            q.dequeue()
            print("Completed job " + q.current.job_ID + " in " + str(int(q.time_elapsed)) + " seconds.")
        if 'active' in line:
            q.active_jobs()
            print("Total number of jobs: " + str(len(q.active_jobs.temp)))
            print("Average priority: " + str(q.active_jobs.average))
```

I am trying to print the last two lines but that is where the error is occurring. 
The error I am getting is: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'temp'.

This is the function within the class:

```
def active_jobs(self):
        if self.head == None:
            pass
#             print("No Jobs Available. ")
        else:
            current = self.head
            self.temp = []
            while current:
                self.temp.append(current.get_data())
                current = current.get_next()
            return self.temp
#             print("Total number of jobs: " + str(len(self.temp)))
            self.priority = []
            for i in range(len(self.temp)):
                self.priority.append(self.temp[i][2])
            x = [int(i) for i in self.priority]
            self.average = sum(x) / len(x)
            return self.average
```

Comment: functions don't have attributes, class instances do... just delete the `active_jobs` to get: `q.temp` and `q.average`

Comment: local variables, by definition, are not accessible outside the function scope they are created in. However, it seems you are trying to access instance attributes, not local variables. regardless, you need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Tomerikoo well, functions *can* have attributes, indeed, they are merely instances of the `function` class. However, their local variables are not magically accessible as attributes, which is what the OP seems to assume is the case.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I tried just putting q.temp and q.average but I keep getting the error: 'Queue_' object has no attribute 'temp'

Comment: @AmanDhaliwal because you never assigned to `self.temp` yet in that instance.

Comment: Yes, by calling `active_jobs()`. And @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the clarification, sorry for the mislead

Comment: @Tomerikoo likely, when called the first time, `.active_jobs` hits the `if` branch, and never assigns to `self.temp`. Impossible to know without a [mcve], but that is my guess

Comment: Agree... I guess we will have to at least see the class

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga , I thought I had called active_jobs in the line q.active_jobs() right above the last two print statements, how should I call it to assign self.temp to the instance ?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I thought I had already called active_jobs() in the line above the last two print statements, how else should I call it?

Comment: @AmanDhaliwal yes, but notice, `self.temp` only gets assigned to in one of the two conditional branches. So it may not exist after `.active_jobs` is called.

Comment: Try `q.temp` and `q.average`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah yes that explains it, thanks a ton

Comment: hmmmm, `active_jobs` has two return statements in the `else` suite - half of that suite never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

`active_jobs` *creates* the `temp` instance attribute. Assuming the instance is `q`; access that attribute with `q.temp`.